# SSIS ADO Net Destination Errors

Tags: error-handling, ssis

I'm having a great deal of trouble converting errors into warning in my package.  The package reads from a csv file and inserts the data into a table.  If there are any issues with the data i want an email sent to the owners. I don't want an error message for myself but i do want the package to finish execution.

I've tried hanging a script component off the ADO Net destination error stream.  When the error (Can't insert dbnull into table) occurs the scrip component is never called.  I want to kill certain errors and convert them to warning with meaningfull messages and send that to the users.  I have been using the OnWarning and OnError events to do this

Issues that i have come across are that i have a number of steps in the dataflow and if a warning/error does occur there is now way to determine which task caused it.

In addition the Error output on the ADO NET called "Set this value to selected cells" always reverts back to "Fail Component" no matter what i change it to.

Why doesn't the Error stream run ? How do i prevent the error event ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSIS Cancel error events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667526/ssis-cancel-error-events)

Comment: Did you put any block after ADO Destination? Put a rowcount, drag a red error arrow to this Rowcount. Then go to Error Output of your destination and select Redirect Output.
Here you can also put a `Derived Column` block with a Replace option and specify formulas checking if it's empty.